# Which activity yields the most experience?

Tags: final-fantasy-brave-exvius

I would like to find an efficient way to level up my units, and I'm not sure which activity I should be using to do so.

- Story missions
- Repeat story missions
- Exploration quests
- Colosseum
- Vortex quests

I seem to get the most exp from exploration, as I can complete lots of battles in a single go, for just the energy cost of entering the area.

I'm not sure if that's the most efficient as I have to move the character around to start battles, whereas repeat missions I can leave the team on 'Auto', but will use more energy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Brave Exvius Wiki has a [page that described the best energy used to experience gained ratio](https://exviuswiki.com/Best_places_to_farm#Unit), split out by the furthest major location you've discovered (how far along you are in the story).

In general (with the exception of early story locales), exploration quests do have a better energy cost/experience potential ratio, and this ratio rises for explorations found later in the story progress. However, there is a time and "attention" cost you must commit with explorations. Instead of being able to just hit "repeat" or "auto" and be done in 3 minutes, you have to take the time and seek out all those battles to get the full potential experience gain.

The other option is to do the Chamber of Experience - ADV in the Chamber of Desires Vortex location. While offering a lesser energy/experience ratio than some exploration quests (30000-31000 exp/15 energy, ~ 2000 exp/energy), this is the best way to play a quick burst (5 minutes or so), get a good amount of experience, and continue with your day.

Chamber of Experience - ADV also allows you to quickly level up one unit, if you wanted to focus on a single unit's advancement. This method is much easier to do here than on a full exploration quest, due to quest duration and enemy difficulty. Since experience is split between all units in your party, you could...

1. Create a one-man team with **only** the unit you want to focus on leveling up.
2. Select a high-level friend to bring along with you to the Chamber of Experience - ADV. This would preferably be a unit that has a good AOE (Firaga/Thundaga/Blizzaga, Scattershot, Bladeblitz, Chainsaw, etc.) or a move that can still attack multiple enemies per turn (Barrage). With a max-level friend set up for high damage, each wave can be beaten in one turn.
3. Have your friend unit use his high-damage move, just keep hitting the repeat button. Beat the four waves, earn a quick 30,000 experience for your one unit.

Answer (score 2):

[king14nyr is correct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/281876/108003) that the Chamber of Experience - ADV is the simplest way to go, easy to overcome with just a decent friend unit, and has good experience competitive with more difficult options.

**New Story Dungeons**

However, now that Olderion has been released, there are new story dungeons that give higher XP/energy than the chamber. At the time of writing, these have not been added to [the wiki's Dungeon Experience Chart](http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Dungeon_Experience_Chart).

You only need to spend six energy to do any of the missions in Olderion's first dungeon, Argus Plains. You won't get quite as much unit experience per energy as in the chamber, but you get much more rank experience and gil. The final mission in this dungeon, Attack of the Raptor, awards about 8200 unit experience, for 1367/energy, in addition to about 210 rank experience and about 900 gil. You can probably just auto through the whole thing if you have a friend unit with 600+ attack.

The last mission in the Shipwreck dungeon, The Charming Beast, also only requires only six energy. It awards about 12300 unit experience, for 2050/energy, and also about 230 rank experience and about 1100 gil. I have a friend Noctis with 700+ attack that can clear the mission himself, on auto. A much weaker collection of heroes could clear it if you paid attention, primarily when fighting the mermaids on the last wave.

Later dungeons require more energy per mission, resulting in less experience per energy throughout most of the rest of Olderion, if not all of it.

**Metal Cactuars**

Really, though, my characters make their biggest leaps in level when there is an event going that provides lots of metal cactuars, particularly metal gigantuars.

For instance, during [the recent Type-0 event](http://exvius.gamepedia.com/Akademeia), you could buy up to 100 metal gigantuars from King Mog for only 100 phantoma each. Each one gives a unit 30000 xp, which is as much as a full run through the chamber. This means that, if you spend all the phantoma on gigantuars, a single run through one of the event missions nets you *much* more experience per energy than the chamber. The exact numbers will vary depending upon a number of factors, but I was getting 500-700 phantoma per 8-10 energy run. Doing the PRO run for 10 energy, getting 700 phantoma, and spending all of it on gigantuars nets almost 220,000xp, for about 22,000/energy.